# Machine crash when publishing a message with Rebus and a database connection enlisted in a transaction scope

Tags: .net, nservicebus, transactionscope, rebus

Let's suppose I have Rebus and a database connection (e.g. sql server connection) enlisted in a transaction scope. There will be some database operations executed on the database connection, and some messages published by Rebus, and the transaction scope will be not escalated to MSDTC (I checked there is no distributed transaction on Windows and also this scenario works on Linux as well where MSDTC is not supported). Complete() is called on the transaction scope, which instructs both the database connection and Rebus to commit. Now let's suppose that the database connection commits first and succeeds, and before Rebus can commit (=publish the messages), the machine crashes. What would happen? I can think of these scenarios:

1. The database operations are committed, but no messages are published (incorrect state).
2. The database operations are rolled back (not sure by who as MSDTC would not be involved, and when the machine restarts I don't think anybody would check what happened with the transaction during the crash), and no messages are published (correct state).
3. The database operations are committed, and messages are published (by who?) after the machine restarts (correct state).

Also, I checked the same scenario with NServiceBus, and when used with MSMQ, the transaction scope is escalated to MSDTC, and the creators of NServiceBus claim that there would be always a correct outcome of the transaction scope - either all committed or all rolled back, no matter if the machine crashes at any point of the transaction scope.

Comment: > and the creators of NServiceBus claim
Could you do me a favor and clarify where you read this? If we can do a better job explaining this, we would appreciate learning where we didn't do well enough.

Comment: 1/2 regarding "the creators of NServiceBus claim ..." - this was my impression from Udi Dahan talk: https://vimeo.com/111998645 (time 12:42 - "DTC solves all those problems for you", time 14:39 "once and only once message delivery which the DTC gives you"). He talks about an implementation in NServiceBus 5 which should be as reliable as DTC without using DTC, and should withstand crashes and be reliable when crashing at any line of code. This talk gave me an impression that you can just use NServiceBus with MSMQ/sql server and DTC, and trust that "it just works". Is is not the case?

Comment: 2/2 Are there cases where NServiceBus with MSMQ/sql server and DTC would not "just work"? e.g. a crash of a machine at some special point where things would not work as expected - messages incorrectly not published, or published twice or multiple times?

Comment: Just a ballpark number, but MSMS + SQL is about 99.99% reliable. If you send 5 messages per second, 300 per minute, 18k per hour, 6.5 million per year, then 657 messages per year might never arrive. Again, just a ballpark number. It's likely less worse. But it IS POSSIBLE because nothing is 100% fail-safe.

Comment: And that is WITH msdtc. The number of lost messages is likely to increase exponantially when you're not using distributed transactions. The outbox can fix a lot of those.

Comment: Duplicate messages (or message processed more than once) will happen in every single system using messaging.

Comment: The alternative to MSDTC, as in no distributed transactions, is already bad. Having no messaging is even worse. Because only in logfiles you might be able to spot that something went wrong. But your order (or whatever was inside the message) is completely gone.

Comment: But as always, there are trade-offs. The answer is always "it depends".
Again, if you want to get in contact and discuss more, let me know: https://particular.net/contactus

Comment: Dennis, thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When handling a message, Rebus performs its work in this order:

1. Your handler is executed (possibly involving a database transaction to commit your own work)
2. Outgoing messages are sent
3. The incoming message is removed from the queue

As the world is full of failure, your program may fail at any point between (or during!) these steps.

If a failure occurs before or during (1), then there's no problem, because your own work (at least in this case) is performed within a transaction that can be atomically rolled back.

If something fails after (1) and before fully completing (3), then you get to experience Rebus' "at least once"-delivery guarantee, which means that – in the event of failures like this – messages WILL be processed at least once, which implies that it *could* get handled twice, maybe even more if you're unfortunate.

There's no escaping this fact, so if you care about this situation, you need to make your message handler [idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence).

Idempotency can be achieved in many ways: Sometimes by virtue of an operation being idempotent in itself (e.g. simply upserting the received data, setting values of some fields to a value from the message, etc.), sometimes by relying on being able to discard outdated data (e.g. if you can compare a "last changed" value of your data with an update timestamp from the message).

But sometimes, if your system would end up in a bad state by processing a re-delivered message, you need to meticulously code your way out of it, e.g. by storing the message ID of handled messages in a table with a unique constraint on the ID.

The tricky part is this: True idempotency requires that you emulate all publicly visible behavior, also when a message is processed the 2nd time. This means that all messages sent/published when handling your message must be sent and published the second time also.

As you can probably imagine, implementing true idempotency is not always trivial.

> (...) the creators of NServiceBus claim that there would be always a correct outcome of the transaction scope - either all committed or all rolled back, no matter if the machine crashes at any point of the transaction scope (...)

With distributed transactions and two-phase commit, this cannot be true, as there is the possibility of a third outcome: All transactions acknowledge during the prepare phase, and then one of them fails during the commit phase (because of a network outage, disk full, or some other unrecoverable problem) – then the transaction coordinator has no other choice than to leave the transaction hanging, requiring manuel intervention to make the world continue.

Comment: My scenario is not about handling an incoming Rebus message and potentially handling it twice or multiple-times. My scenario is about handling a web request which represents a command, and the command handler does some DB operations and publishes an event message (that the command has happened) by Rebus, all within a transaction scope. I'd like to know if the machine crashes at precisely the point when the DB operations are committed successfully, but the messages are not yet published by Rebus - is it possible that the messages won't be published at all?

Comment: Short answer then: yes, it’s possible. You basically get to pick which one you commit first, and then there’s always a risk that the second operation was interrupted.

Comment: I just want to point out that network outage or a full disk is not unrecoverable. Those will be handled automatically by DTC when the network reconnects or you clean up the disk space. The data is there, it was persisted as part of the prepare phase. If a disk fail and it NEVER comes back(a fire for example), you can get transactions hanging. That is a very very uncommon scenario today because most production environments are virtualized and use storage solutions that tolerate individual hardware pieces failing.

Answer (score 1):

> Also, I checked the same scenario with NServiceBus, and when used with MSMQ, the transaction scope is escalated to MSDTC, and the creators of NServiceBus claim that there would be always a correct outcome of the transaction scope - either all committed or all rolled back, no matter if the machine crashes at any point of the transaction scope.

As @mookid8000 mentions, there are no 100% guarantees, even when using distributed transactions. The reason for this is the [2 generals problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Generals%27_Problem). But you could say that using distributed transactions beats everything else in terms of reliability. Unfortunately, it creates a lot of overhead and `Serializable` locks on your data in SQL Server. Oracle [doesn't even support it](http://www.bailis.org/blog/when-is-acid-acid-rarely/). Most DBA hate this and for a reason. I've build systems using MSMQ and SQL Server which ran fine, but it requires some thinking.

Another thing is that most resources don't support distributed transactions. As in, everything in the cloud, RabbitMQ and a lot of other technologies.

A good solution mentioned by @mookid8000 is storing the identifier of every single incoming message into a database and verifying if that message was already processed. But it doesn't stop there. Imagine an event being published with identifier `1b068720-b558-4edf-9ebd-7142bc8cd3c0`. Then we try to tell the queue that it can remove the message, but we fail to do so because of an error. When did we store the message identifier in the database and committed that transaction? Did it succeed or not? If we process the incoming message again, will the identifier be found in the database? Possibly, but was that identifier submitted before or after we published the event? Every step can fail!

The question is, will the event be published again? Because if it will, with what identifier? Probably a new unique one, like `00d13f2b-ce5b-4880-9a5b-2cb541015902`. The issue here is, how can the receiving endpoint know this is the same logical message and it should not be processed, because we already processed the message but with another identifier? We need to try to make sure the event is actually published, but also that if we publish it again, it is with the exact same identifier. Otherwise, idempotency on the other side is very hard, if not impossible!

That's where the [Outbox Pattern](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/outbox/) comes in.

As you can see, it's not that easy to build distributed systems and make sure they're fail-safe. You can always [reach out](https://particular.net/contactus) if you have more questions.